# Setup TLS in postfix for local/internet mail in a LAN

Tags: postfix, ssl

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, last updates of today.

postfix: 3.3.0-1ubuntu0.2

openssh: 1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3

I have a small local network with 1 PC (P), 2 laptops (L1/L2) all running Ubuntu, a tablet and 2 smartphones.
Incoming mail (from the internet) is handled by email clients directly.
I want to be able to send mails using postfix with requirements:

R1:    send mail from any P, L1 and L2 to any P, L1, L2

R2:     send mail from any P, L1, L2 to any email account in the internet

R3:     my mail provider requires some TLS-settings, shown below

At the moment I use a rather identical configuration on all three, with these lines in main.cf, which were partly suggested in my provider's forum to get connected in the first place.

```
relayhost = [smtp.mymail.provider]:465
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
```

1. This setup covers R2, but I can't  send mails within the local network. For example sending mail from P to L1 brings this in /var/log/mail.log:

   Oct 20 14:02:58 P postfix/smtp[7453]: SSL_connect error to L1.mylan[192.168.18.21]:25: -1

   Oct 20 14:02:58 P postfix/smtp[7453]: warning: TLS library problem: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

   Oct 20 14:02:58 P postfix/smtp[7453]: 6CE0E2A1138: to=, relay=L1.mylan[192.168.18.21]:25, delay=0.08, delays=0.02/0.01/0.05/0, dsn=4.7.5, status=deferred (Cannot start TLS: handshake failure)

This sounds like a bug in some TLS-library, but:

2. In the TLS_README this setting is strictly discouraged. Instead it suggests a solution putting a similar line in master.cf. I experimented with several lines and options, but had no success.

What I would like to have, is that P is the forwarding server into the internet, and all handle only the local mail transport (in the LAN) themselves.

So here my questions:

1. Is there a simple (and proper) way to do it? How?
2. Shouldn't I use postfix for this? What then?

Regards

Jack

Comment: Really nobody knows an answer?